# How can I completely uninstall and reinstall sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a program using SQLite and have hit a dead end. I accidentally set the default program for opening .sqlite3 files as notepad and in my quest to fix it I think I broke something and now I'm getting error messages. Here's an example

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) file is not a database
[SQL: PRAGMA main.table_info("test")]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

Visiting the link tells me that the error originates from the database driver and at this point I'm in over my head. I was hoping that completely uninstalling the program (maybe including removing all my computer's associations with .sqlite3 files?) might fix it. (I'm on Windows 10)